# Find multiple keywords in a sentence

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to search for multiple keywords in a rather large text document for example: I need to search if regional and New York show up in one sentence. The current script I have only provides me with one or the other but not both.

My current script is:

```
Get-Content <file name>.txt | Select-String '(phrase)'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use a `Where-Object` filter with multiple clauses: `Where-Object { $_ -match 'foo' -and $_ -match 'bar' }`. However, unless your input file has each sentence in a single line you won't be able to match the terms when they are in the same sentence, but on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get results for multiple patterns:

```
get-content "YourTextFile.txt" | select-string -pattern '(regional.*new york)|(new york.*regional)'
```

Essentially, this looks for anything where the two phrases occur in the same line in either order.

Answer (score 0):

Read over this, some of what's in here is what I use to match patterns. Wildcards and a . will be your tickets.
http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex object to perform such a search.  Here is what that would look like:

```
$inFile = get-content c:\temp\test.txt
$matchedLines = New-Object -TypeName System.collections.ArrayList

foreach ($line in $inFile)
{
    $match = [regex]::Match($line, '(?i).*regional.*new york.*|(?i).*new york.*regional.*')
    if ($match.Success -eq $true)
    {
        $matchedLines.Add($match)
    }
}

Write-Output $matchedLines.Value
```